# PySpark - Add a new nested column or change the value of existing nested columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Supposing, I have a json file with lines in follow structure:

```
{
 "a": 1,
 "b": {
       "bb1": 1,
       "bb2": 2
      }
}
```

I want to change the value of key `bb1` or add a new key, like: `bb3`.
Currently, I use spark.read.json to load the json file into spark as DataFrame and df.rdd.map to map each row of RDD to dict. Then, change nested key value or add a nested key and convert the dict to row. Finally, convert RDD to DataFrame.
The workflow works as follow:

```
def map_func(row):
  dictionary = row.asDict(True)
  adding new key or changing key value
  return as_row(dictionary) # as_row convert dict to row recursively

df = spark.read.json("json_file")
df.rdd.map(map_func).toDF().write.json("new_json_file")
```

This could work for me. But I concern that converting DataFrame -> RDD ( Row -> dict -> Row) -> DataFrame would kill the efficiency.
Is there any other methods that could work for this demand but not at the cost of efficiency?

---

The final solution that I used is using withColumn and dynamically building the schema of b.
Firstly, we can get the `b_schema` from df schema by:

```
b_schema = next(field['type'] for field in df.schema.jsonValue()['fields'] if field['name'] == 'b')
```

After that, `b_schema` is dict and we can add new field into it by:

```
b_schema['fields'].append({"metadata":{},"type":"string","name":"bb3","nullable":True})
```

And then, we could convert it to StructType by:

```
new_b = StructType.fromJson(b_schema)
```

In the map_func, we could convert Row to dict and populate the new field:

```
def map_func(row):
  data = row.asDict(True)
  data['bb3'] = data['bb1'] + data['bb2']
  return data

map_udf = udf(map_func, new_b)
df.withColumn('b', map_udf('b')).collect()
```

Thanks @Mariusz

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `map_func` as udf and therefore omit converting DF -> RDD -> DF, still having the flexibility of python to implement business logic. All you need is to create schema object:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import *
>>> new_b = StructType([StructField('bb1', LongType()), StructField('bb2', LongType()), StructField('bb3', LongType())])
```

Then you define `map_func` and udf:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> def map_func(data):
...     return {'bb1': 4, 'bb2': 5, 'bb3': 6}
... 
>>> map_udf = udf(map_func, new_b)
```

Finally apply this UDF to dataframe:

```
>>> df = spark.read.json('sample.json')
>>> df.withColumn('b', map_udf('b')).first()
Row(a=1, b=Row(bb1=4, bb2=5, bb3=6))
```

**EDIT**:

According to the comment: You can add a field to existing StructType in a easier way, for example:

```
>>> df = spark.read.json('sample.json')
>>> new_b = df.schema['b'].dataType.add(StructField('bb3', LongType()))
```

Comment: Seems, the map_func would get a Row. How can I modify the Row b. And I want to set the sum of bb1 and bb2 as the value of new column bb3

Comment: Column `b` will be modified (replaced) by `withColumn('b', something_here)`. Inside `map_func` you can access all variables of `b`, for example to sum bb1 and bb2 udf can look as follows: `map_udf = udf(lambda data: {'bb1': data.bb1, 'bb2': data.bb2, 'bb3': data.bb1 + data.bb2}, new_b)`

Comment: Thanks! However, can we not to hardcode the schema new_b and dict object since when data structure is changed we need to change the code? Can we infer the schema from column 'b' and dynamically build the dict object?

Comment: Your solution is much better. Didn't find that we can get a StructType from StructField with dataType from pyspark docs

Comment: This is the first time I've seen a Row within a Row, and it solved my problem with pyspark inferring the wrong type